# Change diagonal line color in the table (slashbox)

Tags: tables

I want to change the diagonal line color to white (the one at the left top corner in my case).

Here is the image 
[image]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{white}  
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table}
\label{tb35}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|r|*{3}{c|}}\hline
\rowcolor{c1}
\backslashbox{\color{c2}Q\\\color{c2}Metric~}{\color{c2}base~~}
  & \color{c2}3A & \color{c2}1A & \color{c2}3A \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c1}
\color{c2}Q & & & \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c1}
\color{c2}Proposed & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Add a minimal working example.

Comment: that code is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The black diagonal line is set in the current font color (black). Inside the box you are setting the color explicitly (c2). Therefore the example can be extended by adding a color setting (white) right before `\backslashbox`. Then the diagonal line is drawn in the current color (white):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{1,1,0}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table}
\label{tb35}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|r|*{3}{c|}}\hline
\rowcolor{c1}
\color{white}
\backslashbox{\color{c2}Q\\\color{c2}Metric~}{\color{c2}base~~}
  & \color{c2}3A & \color{c2}1A & \color{c2}3A \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c1}
\color{c2}Q & & & \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c1}
\color{c2}Proposed & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

For information. The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own built-in command `\diagbox`. With that command, the color of the diagonal rule is the standard color of the rules of the tabulars (as set by `\arrayrulecolor`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines-except-borders]
\CodeBefore
   \arraycolor{blue!30}
\Body
   \diagbox{\small R}{\small C} & A & B & C \\
   1 \\
   2 \\
   3 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]